# Free GUI Tester for manual users

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, testing, gui-testing

I been trying MS Test manager 2010 and man it sucks bad. It's got huge potential but right now it sucks and is too buggy and crashes on all my development machines every few mins.

So is there any free software what can sort of do it the same thing?

Like what I liked about it is this.

1. It had a nice check list on the side you would go through each step manually and once you verified that step passed you put passed.
2. It was better than word since other people could log in use the same tests.
3. Once you did it manually it had a play back button that you just hit and it would rerun the test with your clicks. At the end you just manually verified if it all passed. This made it faster on trying multiple browsers ( note this is different than programs like selenium)
4. You could write shared steps that you could use in multiple tests and only have to change in one test( even though this also had many problems it is a good concept).

So what is out there. I am doing asp.net mvc, C# and using VS 2010

I am looking something like this ( just free though)

http://www.testuff.com/static/images/screenshots/big/runner.png

Comment: Can you explain how #3 is "different than programs like selenium", since it sounds so similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Or try WebDriver: http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-webdriver.html